# gradle eclipse integration -

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm using a eclipse 4.2 distribution and have installed the gradle eclipse integration plugin from springsource.

When I initially try to create a quick java project with the wizard I get the following error:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at C:\devtools\gradle-1.4\docs\userguide\gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\devtools\gradle-1.4'.
```

When I run `gradle build` in the command line everything's fine.

Any ideas how i could get this to work?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can run gradle in command line successfully, you would want to try to use that gradle in the eclipse plugin.

Set `Preference -> Gradle -> Gradle Distribution -> Folder` to your own gradle distribution that runs fine.